# R - array from matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix (`data1`) and I need to extract one of its columns and store it in memory as an array. What is the best way to do it?

Now I am using `A <- data1[,1]`, but in this way `A` is defined as "large integer" instead than as a matrix.

Comment: Try `data1[,1, drop=FALSE]`

Comment: Thanks! Why do we need to add `drop=FALSE`?

Comment: Please check `?Extract` `drop: For matrices and arrays.  If ‘TRUE’ the result is coerced to
          the lowest possible dimension`

Comment: The phrase "large integer" is a bit odd. Suggests you may be using a non-base package? The other strategy would be to replace the lost dimension attribute. `dim(A) <- c(length(A),1)`